# Set PNG Image from Firestore to UIImage.image --- Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to set this UIImageView image (profileImage) to my downloaded from Firestore. I don't get any error and it runs fine but profileImage contains the view background color, not the the downloaded image from Firestore.

[view the result image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx8CA.jpg)

```
storage = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://senlink-6d966.appspot.com")
profilePath = storage.child("users_profile/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).png")
profilePath?.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("\(error!)")
            } else {
                if let url = url {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let data = UIImage(data: url.absoluteURL.dataRepresentation)
                        self.profileImg.image = data
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `downloadURL` method returns an url to the image data and not the actual image data. To directly download the image data you can use `getData`. Here is the example from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files):

```
// Create a reference to the file you want to download
let islandRef = storageRef.child("images/island.jpg")

// Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
islandRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
  if let error = error {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {
    // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
  }
}
```

This should do what you want:

```
storage = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://senlink-6d966.appspot.com")
profilePath = storage.child("users_profile/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).png")
profilePath?.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
  if let error = error {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {
    // Data for your image
    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.profileImg.image = image
    }
  }
}
```